# Converting JSON datetime object to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

My JSON returns the object as this

```
"/Date(1307514780000+0530)"
```

How do I convert this to my JavaScript date time object?
Also, what does `+0530` mean?

Comment: +0530 is your Timezone you are 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of Greenwich Mean Time.  The rest of it I believe is UNIX Epoch time (milliseconds from 1/1/1970)

Comment: Are you trying to send PHP's DateTime object? This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428598/can-a-json-object-returned-by-php-contain-a-date-object

Comment: Is this the complete response?

Answer (score 6):

By “My JSON”, I surmise that you’re referring to the way that Microsoft ASP.NET passes a date-time object not as you have written, but with a slash also at the end:

```
/Date(1307514780000+0530)/
```

JSON doesn’t support the native JavaScript **Date()** type, so this is actually a simple JSON string, but Microsoft hacks at it a bit more and actually sends this:

```
\/Date(1307514780000+0530)\/
```

And that’s allowed for a JSON string, even if the backslashes aren’t necessary. (The two strings are identical to your JSON client software, but When Microsoft JScript sees these backslashes, it treats it as a special structure. And, yes, this is a supreme hack.)

The value before the sign (which can also be “-”) is the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. The sign and the value after it represent the presentation time zone, which isn’t necessary to convert the value to a native JavaScript **Date()** object. The sign indicates if the time zone is before (+) or after (-) UTC and the numbers are formatted as “HHMM”, where “HH” is the number of hours and “MM” is the number of minutes. (In this instance, “+0530” is the same time zone offset as India Standard Time, aka “IST”.)

To convert it to a native **Date()** object using standard cross-browser-compatible JavaScript:

```
function getDateFromAspString(aspString) {
  var epochMilliseconds = aspString.replace(
      /^\/Date\(([0-9]+)([+-][0-9]{4})?\)\/$/,
      '$1');
  if (epochMilliseconds != aspString) {
      return new Date(parseInt(epochMilliseconds));
  }
}
```

Note that this function doesn’t return anything if the string is not an ASP.NET date-time string. You can compare (===) the result to **undefined** to see if anything was returned.

On my browser, this invocation:

```
getDateFromAspString("/Date(1307514780000+0530)/").toString()
```

returns this string:

```
"Wed Jun 08 2011 01:33:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"
```

**See also:**

- Microsoft MSDN: [ASP.NET AJAX: Inside JSON date and time string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_sidebarb)