# UTC date and time

Tags: php, date, utc

I am trying to parse what I believe to be a `UTC` date, my PHP code seems to output

`/Date(1392233400000+0000)/`

which I can't seem to find any way of turning into a date and time.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: its part of an API. The best I can show is the API example http://developer.seatwave.com/API/method/GetEventByID?apiName=discovery

Comment: Looks like a unix timestamp in thousandths of a second: split on the "+", take the first part and divide by 1000, then treat as a unix timestamp

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have been searching for that format with limited results. That seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Your API is offering you the information in two ways. As JSON objects or XML. Your example is from the JSON part. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749778/php-date-format-date1365004652303-0500) on how to correctly parse it with PHP.

Looks like that in the XML form the date is already in the "usual" UTC format. So You could also parse the XML data if you prefer.

Comment: Im not sure how to parse it as xml, something i need to look into. Thanks anyway. the other thread does the trick