# API returning invalid Date in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, date, curl

I am using an API in my code and the Date i get is something like this

```
"DateOfBirth":Date(-2208960000000-0800)
```

I am using Curl in my php code, If I try the API in fiddler or any REST client I get correct date like `22-3-2010`, I thought that `2208960000000` could be unix timestamp, but seems very odd that how in REST client the response is different and totally different when I use in PHP code,

EDIT:
The response from API is XML but I am using `"Content-type: application/json"` in my CURL, I then use json_Encode() and can easily traverse through API, I think when I get the data by JSON it sends me this "DateOfBirth":Date(-2208960000000-0800)
Any help in this regard?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to generate / parse the date?

Comment: That looks almost like a JSON date from .NET. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format. Unfortunately, PHP's `json_decode()` doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @newfurniturey the date is generated through the API, I am just getting data from the API

Comment: Do you use 32 bit software (on 32 bit system) ? Looks like some kind of overflow, keep in mind JS time's are in milliseconds rather than seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 var isWcfJsonDate = /\/Date(.*)\//.test("Your Date String");
        if (isWcfJsonDate)
        {
                dateStr = dateStr.match(/Date\((.*?)\)/)[1];
                dateValue = new Date(parseInt(dateStr));
                return dateValue;
        }
        dateValue = new Date(dateObject);
        console.log( dateValue); //Use your date value
```

Comment: @rm-rf it's transformed json (form xml), did no one read the question?

Comment: OK, a little search gave me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749778/php-date-format-date1365004652303-0500

Comment: Yeah its js, just I was trying on fiddler so this worked

Comment: As Dan and rm -rf said, it has to be converted to the required formt, something like the above link by @rm -rf posted should work