# how to convert jsonecode /Date(1366585200000+0100)/ back to readable date

Tags: php, json, timestamp

I have this json_ecoded data and I can not figure out how to convert this

```
'firstInvoiceDate' => string '/Date(1363824000000+0000)/' (length=26)
```

back to

```
'firstInvoiceDate' => string '3/21/2013'
```

I have tried `date()` and `strtotime()` but get the wrong results.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: In the question title you specify +0100. Is this also something you need to deal with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749778/php-date-format-date1365004652303-0500

Comment: Thank you Wouter for taking the time to read my question I did read the question ' Convert Json date string to JavaScript date object' but my question is about how to resolve the issue in php and not javascript

Comment: Thank you LearningMode I did a search for this for some reason did not get any meaningful results but yours is the best answer for my project cheers M8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
function convertToDate($d, $format = 'm-d-Y') { 
    // First argument should have format like '/Date(1363824000000+0000)/'
    if (!preg_match("/[\d+-]+/", $d, $matches)) return null;
    return gmdate($format, $matches[0]/1000);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
print convertToDate('/Date(1363824000000+0000)/', 'm-d-Y');
```

Output:

> 03-21-2013