# Unknown date format

Tags: php, date

I got date on this format from an api `\/Date(-73854000000-0500)\/`, 
it should be a birthday date that date is this 30/8/1967 but when i make

```
echo date("j/m/o", strtotime("-73854000000-0500"));
```

it returns "30/11/5399"

Comment: It looks like a timestamp, bit a really weird one...
As @RyanVincent said, did the API have any docs?

Comment: It's already been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749778/php-date-format-date1365004652303-0500

Comment: Time in milliseconds from 1970, offset from UTC.

Comment: thaks i dint saw it @jakubwrona