# c#: Get timezone offset stored in date object

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am getting a date from API response as:

```
string jsonResponse = @"{'endDate': '/Date(-62135578800000-0500)/'}";
```

Now when I deserialize the reponse using NewtonSoft.json I get the result as:

```
MyClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonResponse);
Console.WriteLine(obj.endDate); // 1/1/0001 5:00:00 AM
```

Now again after some operation I have to post the data to the server in that same format of the date I have received:

```
DateTime endDateValue = new DateTime();
endDateValue = obj.endDate

MyClass objNew = new MyClass{
    endDate = endDateValue
};
string jsonPostData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objNew);

string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonPostData);
Console.WriteLine(response);//{"endDate":"0001-01-01T05:00:00+00:00"}
```

Since I don't want this format `"0001-01-01T05:00:00+00:00"`. It should be same as `'/Date(-62135578800000-0500)/'`.

Till now I followed this link to understand the type of format:
[PHP date format /Date(1365004652303-0500)/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749778/php-date-format-date1365004652303-0500)

I am able to get the timestamp like this:

```
DateTime unixStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
long unixTimeStampInTicks = (endDateValue.ToUniversalTime() - unixStart).Ticks;
Console.WriteLine(unixTimeStampInTicks/10000);//-62135578800000
```

Is there any method in `c#` to get the offset value `-0500` present in this date object like in javascript `getTimezoneOffset()` method returns the offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx), not [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) - it's a similar structure, only with an explicit `Offset` property. Plain `DateTime` doesn't have a concept of time zones.

This means using it within `MyClass`, and deserializing to it.

Comment: I am getting this: DateTimeOffset obj1 = endDate;
  Console.WriteLine(obj1.Offset); //00:00:00

Comment: How can I get -0500 as in my date object

Comment: @IBQ: You can't do that if `endDate` is a `DateTime` - you should instead change `endDate` to a `DateTimeOffset`.